# Intellij can't find class in library

Tags: maven, hadoop, intellij-idea

I've got a weird issue. I'm trying to debug a hadoop job. I've created a configuration profile where the main class is `org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar`. I can find this in the browse dialogue by looking under `external libraries`, then the `hadoop-core-xxx.jar`, `org.apache.hadoop`, then `utils` and `RunJar`.

When I try actually running this configuration, it fails with a log message `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar`. The weird thing is that I've got another project in intellij set up *exactly* the same AFAICT which works. But this particular project just refuses to be able to find `RunJar`.

Both have the same maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2-cdh3u6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Both set the working directory to `/usr/local/opt/hadoop121` and both have the `single instance only` box checked. I'm stumped why I can debug with one project but the other can't find the class.

I've synced the project, invalidated caches, confirmed the `hadoop-core-xxx.jar` is listed under `external libraries`... What have I missed? I'm on OSX with the latest version of intellij IDEA.

Comment: Well it is highly difficult to hit but I am taking my chance. Did you check the  "use classpath of module" thing in run configuration dialog? If that is not set it can be the reason.

Comment: Yes that's checked as well :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the hadoop library was `provided`, i.e. excluded from the jar. Commenting out the following line solves this issue:

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```